# Keyboard Layouts Unusable

Tags: keyboard-layout, input-language

I've upgraded Ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04.1.

I have four keyboard layouts in this order: (1) English (US), (2) Serbian (Latin), (3) Serbian, and (4) Greek.

After I start the computer, changing the keyboard layout (with both icon and `Super` + `Space`) doesn't work when I switch from English (US) to Serbian (Latin) or Serbian. I see the language changed on the top-bar icon, but when I type, it's still English (US). When I activate the Greek layout, the problem disappears entirely until the next reboot.

**Edit 1:** The output of the command `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources` is `@a(ss) []`.

**Edit 2:** I'm using Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.1, upgraded from 18.04, and I added the languages via Settings -> Region and Language -> Input Sources while I had Ubuntu 18.04 installed.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson still not working.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson the output is `@a(ss) []`. The question is edited.

Comment: It seems like those layout additions got lost somehow when you upgraded. Do you see them listed if you now open _Settings -> Region & Language_?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I see them.

Comment: That's a mystery to me. One idea: Navigate to the `~/.config/dconf` directory, run the command `mv user user.bak`, and relogin. That would reset a lot of settings, and you would need to re-add the input sources.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson is it going to reset other non-related settings?

Comment: Yes. But the measure can easily be reversed if it proves to not help. (You would just rename the file where the settings are stored, not remove it.)